# How Can I construct an Embedding for $S^n\times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I will like to construct an embedding for $S^n\times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

I have constructed embeddings for similar question (e.g. $S^1\times S^1 \rightarrow S^3$), but I can’t seem to construct one for this question. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can cover the plane with circles centered at the origin and parameterize them by radius. Generalize that.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I don’t know if this is what you mean: $F(x_1,…,x_n,r) = (x_1.f(r),…,x_n.f(r), f(r))$, where $(x_1,…,x_n)$ is on $S^2$ and $f(r)=e^r$.

Comment: Imagine $S^n\subset\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$. Then, your formula would be $F(p,r)=p\cdot e^r$ (notice a point $p\in S^n$ would have coordinates $p=(x_1,\dots, x_{n+1})\in\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$). You’re essentially just thickening a sphere to an annulus.

Comment: @peek-a-boo This is the same as what I wrote, or am I mistaken here?

Comment: You said $(x_1,\dots, x_n)$. It should be $x_{n+1}$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Oh, I see! You just described what is going on geometrically when you said it was about thickening a sphere to an annulus. I still can’t seem to really know what is going on geometrically. That is, I can’t really describe it the way you did. Is there a book you would like to recommend, or is there a simple hack I can use to help me “see” what is really going on?

Comment: i think this just comes down to practice/experience/confidence. I mean I don’t remember seeing this problem ever, but the solution “I’ came up with (there’s Cyclotomic’s comment above as well) is essentially what I’d think of as ‘obvious’ because the sphere naturally sits in $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$, so visualizing that is the first thing I considered. Another thing I guess is just ‘pattern recognition’ since when doing polar coordinate integrals (especially in highly symmetric situations) you always encounter such a decomposition of an annulus into spheres of varying radii.

Comment: So I was thinking “hmmm it would be nice if we had $(0,\infty)$ or $(0,1)$ instead of $\Bbb{R}$, but then this is of course very trivial to arrange (as you did).

Answer (score 0):

The key is to observe that
$$h : S^n \times (0,\infty) \to \mathbb R^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}, h(x, t) = t x$$
is a diffeomorphism. Its inverse is
$$g : \mathbb R^{n+1} \setminus \{0\} \to S^n \times (0,\infty), g(y) = (\frac{y}{\lVert y \rvert},\lVert y \rvert) .$$

Then
$$\psi :  S^n \times \mathbb R \to  \mathbb R^{n+1}, \psi(x,t) = (\ln t)x$$
is an embedding.

Note that all maps occurring here are smooth.